# Why type NSString cannot be returned by value?

Tags: objective-c

Why can't NSString be retuned by value? Why when we return an object of NSString type we don't need to use symbol of pointer?
While in declaration of function's returned type symbol of pointer is required:

```
NSString* boolString (BOOL yesNO)
{
    if (yesNO==NO) {
        return (@"NO");
    } else {
        return (@"YES");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSString`, like any other instance of Cocoa classes, are always passed by pointer. That’s why the `@` symbol defines a statically-allocated `NSString` object, and returns its pointer.

See this question for the reasons why: [Why do Objective-C objects have to be dynamically allocated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5844284/126995)